# Add java kernel to jupyter without using anaconda

Tags: jupyter-notebook

`anaconda` does not install properly on my system - after multiple attempts.

The `scijava-jupyter-kernel` *only* describes how to be installed using `anaconda`.

https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos

[image]

Can this be installed  "natively" - ie through the standard `jupyter` kernel installation process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm successfully install that java kernel without using [anaconda](https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava).

I'm using Linux Fedora 28 64-bit, so this following examples work for me (not sure if you'll need to adapt in any way).

First, verify your java installation. I used sdk 11.0.1 downloaded [from here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk11-downloads-5066655.html):

Next, install the kernel: after unzip, goes to the folder and runs the follow command:

```
chmod u+x gradlew && ./gradlew installKernel
```

Alternatively, you can try [this one](https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava/releases/download/v1.2.0/ijava-1.2.0.zip).

and install just with the command-line:

```
python3 install.py
```

Read the readme file carefully on:
https://github.com/SpencerPark/IJava